# Azure Data Factory Global variables

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

If I define a global variable at the management panel level.  Is that variable accessible by other concurrently running data factories?

I am looking into using a global as a validation flag as it will be available as a return value from child pipelines. And I do not want a concurrent data factory invocation to have scope into that variable.

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to Global parameters in Azure Data factory. If that is the case, then the answer is `No`. Global parameters are constants across a particular Data Factory that can be consumed by a pipeline in any expression. You cannot use that global parameter in other data factories except the one in which it was created. But it can be referenced in other pipelines within the same data factory.

Comment: Let me clarify my requirement to ensure I understand your answer: 

My-Data-Factory:  define global a = 1 

My-Data-Factory invoked  sets global =2 within a pipeline.

My-Data-Factory invoked within a few microseconds by a 2nd trigger  is this global a 1 ? or is it 2 ?

Comment: If your `My-Data-Factory` has a global parameter `global = 1` which means it's default value is set to`1`, and unless you assign a different value at pipeline runtime (may be using a dynamic expression) for every instance (concurrent) the parameter default value will be `1`. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the **@KranthiPakala-MSFT**, Yes Global parameters are constant, and we cannot use a Global parameter of one ADF in another ADF.

But if you want to use it, store it in a file in blob using copy activity source additional column.

Then use this file value by lookup activity in another ADF workspace.

Or **store it in a set variable**.

[image]

[image]

Run this pipeline and in another ADF get this activity run details by using the below [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run?tabs=HTTP) in web activity.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Comment: Why use a blob for a global variable over this ADF option? I'm new to both so excuse my ignorance. My use case is using a variable across logic apps.